# Direction rtl to all page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a long html page.
I want to change the direction of all text/tables to rtl.
How can i do that to all page instead of to change to any element the direction to rtl?

Thanks.

Comment: How can i do that with javascript? i can add attribute to body element?

Comment: Yes. `document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### **Using CSS:**

```
* {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

### **Using JavaScript:**

```
var children = document.children;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   children[i].style.direction = "rtl";
}
```

OR

```
document.body.style.direction = "rtl";
```

OR ( from `evolutionxbox` comment )

```
document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')
```

### **Using JQuery *(even if you are not asking about)*:**

```
$("html").children().css("direction","rtl");
```

### **Inline Coding:**

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

OR

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Or `document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')`

Comment: Thanks, its possible that document.children is undefined?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner No. `document.children` returns at least one item (`body` - because it is automatically added by the web browser event if it doesn't exist in your code).

Answer (score 5):

The **direction** property in CSS sets the direction of of content flow within a block-level element. This applies to text, inline, and inline-block elements. It also sets the default alignment of text and the direction that table cells flow within a table row.you can use

```
body {
  direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
}
```

**or** There is an HTML attribute for setting the direction as well

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

***It is recommended you use the HTML attribute, as that will work even if CSS fails or doesn't affect the page for any reason.***

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery.

```
$('body').children().css('direciton','rtl');
```

Or use pure Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('Body')[0].style.direction = "rtl"
```

Comment: amm..its possible that i have no <body> tag in the .html page?

Comment: I don't think so. anyway, you can use any element (like Div container) and use the same code....

Comment: Refrain from giving jQuery answers if the OP hasn't tagged the question with it.

Comment: @CSharpBeginner - the body tag will be added automatically by the browser if it is not present in the HTML.

Comment: You can peform the same with pure Javascrip:document.getElementsByTagName('Body')[0].style.direction = "rtl"

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
 document.body.style.direction= "rtl";
```

HTML

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Or `document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')`

Comment: Yes ,we can do this

Answer (score 0):

using **css**:

```
html * {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

using **jQuery**:

```
$('html').children().css('direction','rtl');
```

Comment: Refrain from giving jQuery answers if the OP hasn't tagged the question with it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but i have added css solution first.. jquery is aditional

Comment: That's fine, but please include a non-jquery JS solution. As that is what the OP has asked for. *"How can i do that with javascript? i can add attribute to body element?"*