# Defining page direction dynamically - Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set the page direction (RTL or LTR) dynamically on my Vue js project.

However, if I try to set dynamically, e.g using a variable called direction, nothing happens (it keeps the standard value, LTR value):

```
  <html lang="en" v-bind:dir="direction" id="example-1">
    <head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <p>Write this text right-to-left!</p>          
      </div>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"> 
   </script>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>

var test=new Vue({
el: '#example-1',
data: {
    counter: 0,       
    direction:'rtl'
  },
  methods: {
    greet: function (event) {
        this.direction='rtl';
    }
}
});
```

Shows the following error,
[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to  or  - mount to normal elements instead.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please post your code that calls `new Vue(...)`

Comment: var test=new Vue({
    el: '#example-1',
    data: {
        counter: 0,       
        direction:'rtl'
      },
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
            this.direction='rtl';
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 3):

Try mounting in the `div` instead of the `html` element.  And use CSS `direction`

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div v-bind:style="{direction}" id="example-1">
        <p>Write this text right-to-left!</p>          
      </div>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"> 
   </script>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Steven Spungin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5093961/steven-spungin) pointed out, you should mount your Vue app in div instead of the html element.

Then you can handle your page direction dynamically in a function like this :

```
...
methods:{
    ...
    setPageDirection(dir){
        document.body.style.direction = dir
    }
    ...
}
...
```

You can find more ways to set page direction on this thread : [Direction rtl to all page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346671/direction-rtl-to-all-page/38346931)